# 500 error code internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i recently hosted an asp.net mvc4 website to a webhost server, before deployment everything worked fine including remote database connections, but after moving published files to the hosting server i cant browse the site remotely. i get a 500- internal server error(There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.) i have reviewed my web.config files but i cant find anything. after contacting my hosting provider i was asked to add

```
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>,
```

i did that but am still getting the same error. please guys i need your help.thanks

here is the code snipet of my web.config xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--

    -->
    <configuration>
    <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework"  
       type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>
   <connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=mssql.mydomain.com,port;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;user id=UserID;password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>



 <system.web>
 <authentication mode="None" />
 <compilation  targetFramework="4.5" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>

 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

 </system.webServer>
 <runtime>
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Set this to on, you'll then see the actual error displayed to allow you to debug the error. <customErrors mode="On"/>

Comment: @danm thanks for ur suggestion......well i actuall had to republish the app and its working fine now